# Conditional member type based on other members types

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to specify multiple possible member types based on specific conditions ? For example, giving the following type:

```
interface DataItem {
    value: boolean | Date | string | string[];
    options: undefined | string[];
}
```

I would like to specify that if:

- `value` is of type `boolean` or `Date` then `options` **must** be of type `undefined`.
- `value` is of type `string` or `string[]` then `options` **must** be of type `string[]`.

Is there anyway today to specify the above constraints in current version of TypeScript (2.2)? Also, if there is then I am assuming that adding type guards on one member should apply to other members, i.e.:

```
let data: DataItem;
if (typeof data.value === 'boolean') {
    data.options = ['a']; // => Error Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
}
```

---

I tried the following but that did not work:

```
interface BooleanOrDateItem {
    value: boolean | Date;
}

interface StringOrStringArrayDataItem {
    value: string | string[];
    options: string[];
}

type DataItem = BooleanOrDateItem | StringOrStringArrayDataItem;

let data: DataItem;

if (typeof data.value === 'string') {
    // I would expect this to work but the compiler complains 
    // => Property 'options' does not exist on type 'DataItem'.
    //          Property 'options' does not exist on type 'BooleanOrDateItem'.
    data.options = ['a'];
}
```

Explicitly casting to `StringOrStringArray` obviously works

```
if (typeof data.value === 'string') {
    (<StringOrStringArrayDataItem>data).options = ['a'];
}
```

but shouldn't the compiler do that on my behalf since it has enough information to infer that `data` is of type `StringOrStringArrayDataItem`?

Comment: I feel that this approach is not going to work, I would use 'any' data type or create multiple interfaces and work out which you need using a factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [User-defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). After every `if` statement, TypeScript narrows the type of `dataItem` to the correct type if the return value is `true`.

```
interface DataItem {
    value: boolean | Date | string | string[];
    options: undefined | string[];
}

interface BoolOrDateDataItem extends DataItem {
    value: boolean | Date;
    options: undefined;
}
interface StringDataItem extends DataItem {
    value: string | string[];
    options: string[];
}

function isBoolOrDateDataItem(dataItem: DataItem): dataItem is BoolOrDateDataItem {
    return typeof dataItem.value === 'boolean' || dataItem.value instanceof Date;
}

function isStringDataItem(dataItem: DataItem): dataItem is StringDataItem {
    return typeof dataItem.value === 'string' || dataItem.value instanceof Array;
}

let dataItem: DataItem = {
    value: true,
    options: undefined
} // Or whatever it may be

if (isStringDataItem(dataItem)) {
    dataItem.value = new Date(); // TypeScript warns value must be string | string[] - knows it is a StringDataItem here
} else if (isBoolOrDateDataItem(dataItem)) {
    dataItem.value = true; // No error
}
```

It's definitely a bit verbose, but seems to be the recommended way of doing things.